# Use OAuth2 with Spinnaker

Tags: oauth-2.0, spinnaker, django-oauth

So I have two services A and B, and A needs to login to B via Oauth2. B is using is using [Django OAuth Toolkit](https://django-oauth-toolkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) as its Oauth2 provider. Service A is also a Django app (not really important). We are introducing [Spinnaker](https://www.spinnaker.io/) into our stack so that we can get unique staging environments (i.e. `someUniqueString.staging.com`) and remove the bottleneck of waiting for others to be done with staging before deploying to it.

The issue is that OAuth2 does not support wildcard subdomains in its callback URLs for security purposes. Is there a workaround for this or has anyone figured out how to combine Spinnaker and Oauth2? It would kinda defeat the purpose of all this automation if we had to go into the Django OAuth Toolkit after every staging deploy to add the generated URL to the list of callback URLs.

Comment: i set up Oauth with bitbucket. It required a static Callback URL. It wasnt that painful and spinnaker gueses the URL resolution. Do you have an update on this? or more details that you can share. You should use Oauth custom provider.